# How to mock @Inject('window') in Jasmine Test

Tags: angular, jasmine

Is it possible to mock an injected service into a Jasmine test? My constructor contains:

```
@Inject('window') private window: any
```

And my `providers` array inside of my Test contains:

```
providers: [{ provide: 'window', useValue: mockWindowService }]
```

My `mockWindowService` is:

```
const mockWindowService = {
    history: {
        pushState: () => ''
    },
    location: {
        href: 'href',
        origin: 'origin'
    }
};
```

I'm wondering how I can properly mock and test this. For example, I'd like to do the following:

```
const assignSpy: jasmine.Spy = spyOn(window.location, 'assign');
expect(assignSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('my/custom/path');
```

How can I accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: What problems are you running into with creating spies on your `mockWindowService` variable?